# Xamarin - error with layout file

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to create a cross platform native app using Xamarin studio installed on windows.It currently targets Android.I am getting the following error.

> Projects\sample\Android\Resources\layout\Main.axml(1,1): Error CS0116:
>   A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
>   (CS0116) (sample.Android)

This is the generated layout file,I have not made any changes to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is an Android layout file, not a Xamarin.Forms UI.

Comment: @Jason File->new->Blank app (Xamarin.Forms.Shared) This is what I have selected.How Do I use Xamarin forms for a cross platform app inside Xamarin studio.